# Gitlab fatal: unable to access '.......' SSL Certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I just started getting this error message in Gitlab today when I push my changes to my code repo in Gitlab.

> Gitlab fatal: unable to access '.......' SSL Certificate problem:
> unable to get issuer certificate

[image]

I have stopped and started the gitlab runner using `gitlab-runner stop` then `gitlab-runner start` however this error message persists everytime I push my changes to gitlab.

Answer (score 7):

Open terminal in the text editor and paste the following line and hit enter:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend channel
```

That should resolve the issue. It did for me.

Comment: This is what worked for me: git config --global http.sslBackend schannel
Note the "s" in front of the channel

Answer (score 0):

With some investigation online I found this posted 9 months ago (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4805)  which is weird as this issue hasn't occurred until now for me.

In short the issue listed there is known to occur in **Gitlab Runner version 12.4.0** and from what you can see in my error output I do have **Gitlab Runner version 12.4.0**

So the fix is to upgrade my Gitlab Runner version, which I did to the latest which is **version 13.2.2**

To upgrade I ran this command: `rpm -Uvh gitlab-runner_<arch>.rpm`

To find out what to replace `<arch>` with you can simply run `gitlab-runner -v` on your server where you have gitlab runner installed and it'll show you the OS/Arch.  Here's a sample output:

```
Version: x.x.x
Git revision: ......
Git branch: x-x-stable
GO version: gox.xx.x
Built: <date and time>
OS/Arch: <grab the Arch field here to replace the **arch**  field above with>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this issue is when the remote repository is setup to use SSH only but you have an http/s remote setup for the local repository.

Fixes:

1. Change the remote repository to accept all types of connections.
2. Change the local repositories' remote to SSH.